# Why does UICollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems forget I selected an item in viewWillAppear?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

This used to work in iOS 6 but is failing in iOS 7

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    NSArray *selectedPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems;
    NSAssert(selectedPaths.count == 1, @"viewWillAppear - Should be 1 but is %d", selectedPaths.count);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *selectedPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems;
    NSAssert(selectedPaths.count == 1, @"cellForItemAtIndexPath - Should be 1 but is %d", selectedPaths.count);
}
```

The assertion in cellForItemAtIndexPath fails:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'cellForItemAtIndexPath - Should be 1 but is 0'

I select an item in viewWillAppear with the selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath API but by the time cellForItemAtIndexPath is called the collectionView has forgotten that anything was selected. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh!

```
UICollectionViewController.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear
```